# Performing point distance analysis using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, proximity

I have two point feature classes A & B, point A is more dense while point B is less dense, I want to carry out a proximity check for points from point A that is closest to points from point B.
And also tweak it such that, for any of point A closest to point B, it mustn't be closest to another point of point B.
Is there a way this can be done using ArcMap?